# How to populate additional fields on a join table (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, join, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I'm essentially using the example `has_many` through setup from the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

I have one model called `options` and another called `registrations`. When you register for an event you can choose multiple `options` and each option has it's own *time* and *attendee limit* which are unique to the registration entry.

My join table is `registrations_options` and has an `option_id` and a `registration_id` that are populating just fine. But the join table also has columns named `time` and `attendee_limit`. For the life of me I can't figure out how to populate them from the form.

I've tried a bunch of things, but this is just the last *trial* state of my form code for this section:

```
#models/registration.rb
class Registration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :registrations_options
  has_many :options, through: :registrations_options
...

#models/option.rb
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :church
  has_many :registrations_options
  has_many :registrations, through: :registrations_options
...

#registrations_controller.rb
...
def new
  @registration = Registration.new
  @registration_form = RegistrationForm.new(@registration, registrations_path)
end
...

#admin/registrations/partials/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @registration_form do |f| %>
<%= render partial: '/admin/registrations/partials/options', locals: {options: @registration_form.options, selected_church: @registration_form.selected_church, registration: @registration_form.registration} %>
...

#admin/registrations/partials/_options.html.erb
<%= collection_check_boxes :registration, :option_ids, options, :id, :ministry_area do |b| %>
  <%= b.check_box + " " + b.label %><br/>
  <div class="field" id="additional-info-<%= b.object.id %>">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <legend>Additional Information</legend>
      <div class="additional-info-container">
        <div class="field">
          <%= label_tag "What time do you want to observe the environment(s)?" %>
          <div class="radio">
            <% b.object.available_service_times.split(', ').each do |time| %>
              <%= radio_button_tag 'registrations_options[service_time][' + b.object.id.to_s + ']', time %> <%= time %><br> #this is one of the lines in question!
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= label_tag " How many people will be observing this environment?" %>
            <%= select_tag 'registrations_options[attendees]', options_for_select((1 .. b.object.attendee_limit).to_a) %> #this is the other line in question!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you also have a registrations_option model with belongs_to associations with :registration and :option?

Comment: Use [`accepts_nested_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: Hey Steve, yeah I do.

Comment: max - so it looks like I would add `accepts_nested_attributes` to the registration model to accept options? but i still don't get how to use `form_for` to make the form field actually populate the join table.